# using camera sensor in gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, camera, pr2-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

how can i use the camera sensor?
I configurated my camera in the urdf file, now i need to see what the camera see.

could you suggest me same examples or documentation?

thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11987/using-camera-sensor-in-gazebo-simulation/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to use the [image_view](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view) package to see your image.

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/your/image_topic
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-11-23**:
You might want to look into compression and theora, but that might not apply to your application.

**Comment by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on 2011-11-23**:
it was so simple. thanks! there are other intersting things that i need to learn from imade_view stack?